# ASP.NET MVC form submits to index instead to submitting to the right action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action, forms, http-post

I crated a form that is to be used as a partial view.

I placed a breakpoint at the 'Save' action, and when I click the submit button, it validates the data, but never reaches the action, instead the `Index` action is reached several times!

Here is the code:

```
@model Models.Category

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Categories", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Category</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryId)

    <p>@((Model.CategoryId > 0 ? "Edit" : "New") + " category")</p>

    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Title)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Description)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Description)
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    </p>
  </fieldset>
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(Category category)
{
  throw new Exception("Exception has been thrown!");
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens when I hit 'Save', validation error shows up, but the `Save` action is not called, nor is the exception ever thrown.
Instead, the `Index` action is triggered!

[image]

What else can I check to track down the issue? Who is redirecting the page to index???

You can see the output HTML [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9DHW/).

Comment: Weird, your controller is definitely called `Categories` yeah? When it passes validation, does it still submit to `Index`?

Comment: @Shinny Can you post the output HTML (from the browser's dev tools) of that opening `form` tag?

Comment: @mattytommo http://jsfiddle.net/gRjeT/

Comment: Looks okay, is there a redirect to Index in your save method? Can you post the code for the `Save` method (the actual body)

Comment: Could it be that your authentication cookie is expired, and thus it's redirecting to your home index page?

Comment: @mattytommo I even tried throwing an exception at the entrance of the `Save` action, nothing happens.

Comment: @MystereMan, no it has nothing to do with the authentication. The user is authenticated.

Comment: @Shimmy - are you absolutely sure you're rendering the correct view?  Did you put a breakpoint in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in the `RouteConfig.cs` file.

There was a wrong mapping that confused the routing and I guess it used the `Index` action as a default instead of the specific action that wasn't found due to the wrong setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `Action` and `Controller` in the `BeginForm` method:

```
Html.BeginForm("Save", "YourController", FormMethod.Post)
```

Comment: That wasn't the issue, sorry for omitting the `BeginForm` arguments in my post, it's now there, please update or delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using unobtrusive validation?  If so, the validation is happening client side, assuming that your model specifies Title is requires, which according to your code looks likely.

If you want your action to be called regardless of the validation state, you will need to do your validation in your action, rather than through unobtrusive client side validation.

Comment: I disabled the validation and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to ValidateAntiForgeryToken may be your action method is not map with your form request remove this tag or do this according to giving in this tutorial:

- http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

and also see this:

- [ValidateAntiForgeryToken purpose, explanation and example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621934/could-you-explain-validateantiforgerytoken-purpose-and-show-me-example-about-val)

Comment: I removed it from both the view and the action, and the *Save* button runs the `Index` action.

Comment: Note that this should be placed on your code: Html.BeginForm("Save", "Categories", FormMethod.Post) if you want to used `Save` action

Comment: It's in my form as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

The error can also occur if the `[Authorize]` tag is at the top of the controller. If the user is not logged in, actions not marked with `[AllowAnonymous]` will not load.